# Why was "CentOS 7 DVD ISO vs Everything ISO different" closed as unclear?

Tags: discussion

I just tried to download CentOS Linux and when I go to the official download site, it offers either DVD ISO or Everthing ISO. There’s nowhere obvious on that page that explains the difference, so I Googled the two terms and the top hit is [CentOS 7 DVD ISO vs Everything ISO different](https://superuser.com/questions/814467/centos-7-dvd-iso-vs-everything-iso-different). The question captured what I wanted to know and the accepted answer was what I needed.

To me, the question seems reasonably clear, although some of the language isn't great.

Is it just the language that meant it was closed as unclear, or is there something more fundamentally wrong about the question? If I tidied the language, might it get re-opened?

Comment: I suspect it was closed because of the wording of the question.  Without any context as to why the question was being asked, it wasn't clear what the OP was looking for in an answer.  The identical question was asked again more recently.  On the newer one, the question is clearer and the answer is more complete.  It doesn't make sense to simply edit and reopen this one and have two identical questions.  The two should be consolidated or linked.  The simple approach would be to make one a duplicate.  That can be based on either age or quality, a community decision.

Comment: Thanks - I see someone's made it a duplicate now. This should be helpful as that was the top result on Google when I searched

Answer (score 5):

I believe it was taken out of context. I'd suggest editing that original question to include information about what *you* researched about this subject, and hopefully it can be reopened.

Comment: Question wasn't asked by OP, and dates back to september last year

Comment: @sathya I didn't mention it was his :-P

Comment: Thanks. It's been made a duplicate now, so all is good